# HTML table from multiple JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am building a little interactive website for some people to use. I have a lot of it built but am stuck on this part.

There are 4 arrays that are based on a users selections, they start as empty arrays. As a user clicks on an item it's four components are added to each array respectively, they are all numbers.

Item 1: 3,5,7,9

Item 2: 2,4,6,8

```
    var bgArray = [3,2]; 
    var minority = [5,4];
    var poverty = [7,6];
    var lep = [9,8];
```

What I want to do is build an HTML table from the four arrays and have it look like the following. Basically row 1 would be [0] for each array, row 2 would be [1] and so on. I cannot figure out a way to get them to line up. (run code snippet to see table)

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>H1</td>
  <td>H2</td>
  <td>H3</td>
  <td>H4</td>

  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>9</td>

  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I plan to have users make their selections and then click a button to generate the table. They can also deselect an item and regenerate the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to write so far? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: SO make a loop, reference index from each array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric, this code may be what you are requesting. This will help you draw your table with the values of the arrays on a button click.

```js
var bgArray = [3,2,1]; 
var minority = [5,4,3];
var poverty = [7,6,5];
var lep = [9,8,7];

$("button").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Get the length of one array
  var numRows = bgArray.length;
  
  // Clear the table (except first row)
  $("table tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
  
  // Add the rows
  for(var i = 0; i < numRows; i++){
    var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    newRow.append(createNewColData(bgArray[i]));
    newRow.append(createNewColData(minority[i]));
    newRow.append(createNewColData(poverty[i]));
    newRow.append(createNewColData(lep[i]));
    $("table").append(newRow);
  }  
});

// Auxiliar function to render a table data
function createNewColData(data){
  return "<td>" + data + "</td>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add values</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>H1</td>
    <td>H2</td>
    <td>H3</td>
    <td>H4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not sure how your button display will work, but if you update your markup I could update my answer.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: This is my preferred solution as i am already using Jquery. This works great for what I need, nice and simple and integrated great with my existing code. Your button implementation/display worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the arrays (considering that the length of the four matrixes is the same) and build the lines of table:

```js
var bgArray = [3,2]
  , minority = [5,4]
  , poverty = [7,6]
  , lep = [9,8];

var lines = "";
for (let i = 0 ; i < bgArray.length ; i++){
      lines += "<tr>"  
      lines += "<td>" + bgArray[i] + "</td>"      
      lines += "<td>" + minority[i] + "</td>" 
      lines += "<td>" + poverty[i] + "</td>" 
      lines += "<td>" + lep[i] + "</td>" 
      lines += "</tr>"
}

$("table").append(lines);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: thanks so much for this answer. While it did do what I was looking for it did not work as well with my code and this is my mistake. Every time i clicked the button it would add the rows again to the table, over and over. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using any javascript library.

Vanilla Javascript will do

HTML

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var bgArray = [3,2], minority = [5,4], poverty = [7,6], lep = [9,8];

var row = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i < bgArray.length ; i++){
      row += "<tr>" ; 
      row += "<td>" + bgArray[i] + "</td>"  ;    
      row += "<td>" + minority[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "<td>" + poverty[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "<td>" + lep[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "</tr>";
}

var t = document.querySelector('table');

t.innerHTML = t.innerHTML + row;
```

[The JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/Wisdomabioye/nkaq5yhy/)

```js
var bgArray = [3,2], minority = [5,4], poverty = [7,6], lep = [9,8];

var row = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i < bgArray.length ; i++){
      row += "<tr>" ; 
      row += "<td>" + bgArray[i] + "</td>"  ;    
      row += "<td>" + minority[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "<td>" + poverty[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "<td>" + lep[i] + "</td>" ;
      row += "</tr>";
}

var t = document.querySelector('table');

t.innerHTML = t.innerHTML + row;
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
  </tr>

</table>
```